# How to echo inside the js file with wp_localize_script?

Tags: theme-development, wp-localize-script

I have used `wp_localize_script()` to pass a variable to a javascript file.

```
var countries = [searchresults.data];
```

The variable is getting passed but I want it in a js file like below:

```
var countries = [item1,item2,item3];
```

The variable is correct `searchresults.data = item1,item2,item3`, but the countries variable has to be like `var countries = [item1,item2,item3];`
iIam not able to do. Please help

---

This is the $data that I passed

```
 $data = array(
      'data' => $searchresult,
    );
 wp_localize_script( 'searchautocompleter', 'searchresults', $data );
```

Comment: var countries = searchresults.data;

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks ..there was a problem with structure of variable passed..there were quotes around the string which was creating the problem.